# Looking for a reference that shows all the elements that contain a specific attribute in HTML

Tags: html, css, dom

I tried searching for this and I didn't have any luck.

Lets say I want to know all the elements in HTML that has a "background" attribute. I know some browsers might not support this element.

Off the top of my head `<body>, <table>, <etc>` are all elements that support this attribute. But I also know I'm missing a bunch from this list.

```
<body background="url">
```

Is their a resource - that will have a listing of elements each attribute applies to. I know background in the format above is considered obsolete) but it's just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for CSS attribute selectors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

In your particular example you can get all elements with a background attribute from this query:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[background]');
```

Comment: I agree with this, but just because something has an attribute - doesn't make the attribute valid..  for instance <link background="url" href="url"> - I'm assuming it will pull this back, but the background  will not be rendered in HTML because it doesn't apply to the link element.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood your question. What you are asking is really determined by the documents DOCTYPE. This resource shows valid attributes for HTML 4: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html

Comment: I seen that link before, but it only shows that the background attribute applies to the body tag. Which we know isn't the case.

Comment: What the specification states, and what browsers supports are very often two different things...

Comment: I agree - I seen this resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes  but as you can see it doesn't even list the background attribute (most likely because its depreciated) but yet almost all browsers support it on multiple tags.

Comment: I'm quite sure that this is a HTML5 reference, given that it has srcset and other newer attributes listed.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, this is something you can test for yourself in your own browser. If you have an attribute that corresponds directly to a css property, you can use the fact that setting the attribute also sets the property!

In your example, the `background` attribute translates into `background-image`, so you can test as follows...

```html
<div></div>
<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>
<script>
  var result = 'Results:<br>';
  var nodes = document.body.children;
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    node.setAttribute('background', 'bg.png');
    var bgimage = window.getComputedStyle(node).getPropertyValue('background-image');
    if (bgimage!='none')
      result += node.nodeName+' has '+bgimage+'<br>';
  }
  nodes[0].innerHTML = result;
</script>
```

The script loops through the children of `body`, in this case the three elements `div`, `table` and `script`, and assigns `background` attributes to all of them, then reports those elements that now have actual `background-image` styles.

Unsurprisingly, the outcome of the snippet is that `table` supports this, but `div` and `script` do not.